# Error the Syntax SQL

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I have Error the Syntax sql i have two data base and i used the query

```
$sqlinsert="insert into referent 
    (oldReferentId,genderReferent,firstnameReferent,lastnameReferent,
     emailReferent,phoneReferent,faxReferent,type,adressReferent,
     supportOrganization,zipCode,cityReferent,countryReferent,
     mailAverti,blocked,published,validateRight) 
   VALUES 
    (".$tb_user['id'].",'NULL',".$tb_user['name'].",".$tb_user['username'].",".
      $tb_user['email'].",'','',".$tb_user['usertype'].",'','s','z','c','cr','0',".
      $tb_user['block'].",'0','0')
";
$test=@mysql_query($sqlinsert,$db1) or die( mysql_error() . "<br>$sqlinsert" );
```

i get Error the Syntax ,how can i resolved That

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error? What is the query?

Comment: use quotes for string values,

Comment: **1.** That query was a mess, you should clean it up, so that it's easier to read. **2.** You are missing quotes around your strings. **3.** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and **removed entirely** in PHP 7) and you should [stop using them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942) if you can. 
You should choose another API that enables usage of prepared statements, like `mysqli_*` or PDO - see [choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are not using quotes for string value in your SQL Statement:

**Issue in following location:**

```
".$tb_user['name'].",".$tb_user['username'].",".$tb_user['email']."
```

**Modified Statement:**

```
$sqlinsert="insert into referent (oldReferentId,genderReferent,firstnameReferent,
lastnameReferent, emailReferent,phoneReferent,faxReferent,type,adressReferent,
supportOrganization,zipCode,cityReferent,countryReferent,mailAverti,blocked,published,validateRight) 
VALUES (".$tb_user['id'].",'NULL','".$tb_user['name']."',
'".$tb_user['username']."','".$tb_user['email']."','','',
'".$tb_user['usertype']."','','s','z','c','cr','0','".$tb_user['block']."','0','0')";
```

**Side Note:**

`mysql_*` extension is deprecated and close in PHP 7, please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.